# diskutil fails to fix Fusion Drive

Tags: repair, fusion-drive, diskutil, fsck

My iMac suddenly stopped booting, failing to mount the disk at boot.

Running diskutil repair fails with this error:

```
bash-3.2# diskutil repairVolume disk3
Started file system repair on disk3 Macintosh HD
Repairing storage system
Checking volume
disk0s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk1s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk0s2: Scan for Disk Labels
disk1s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Logical Volume Group A8FAA178-6011-40B8-9138-AC3500CE05DA spans 2 devices
disk0s2+disk1s2: Scan for Metadata Volume
Logical Volume Group has a 206 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Load and verify Checkpoint Payload
Load and verify Transaction Segment
Incorporate 0 newer non-checkpoint transactions
Load and verify Virtual Address Table
Load and verify Segment Usage Table
Load and verify Metadata Superblock
Load and verify Logical Volumes B-Trees
Logical Volume Group contains 1 Logical Volume
Load and verify A9822895-14D4-4304-9167-BCD2C5F75269
Load and verify 2323EBF3-1631-4A3E-8078-6B5D506D09CD
Load and verify Freespace Summary
Load and verify Block Accounting
Load and verify Live Virtual Addresses
Newest transaction commit checkpoint is valid
Load and verify Segment Cleaning
The volume A8FAA178-6011-40B8-9138-AC3500CE05DA appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Error: -69846: Unrecognized file system
```

Such error is quite weird considering it was JUST reading information from that filesystem.

How can I fix my disk and recover my files?

Edit: More diskutil output:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group A8FAA178-6011-40B8-9138-AC3500CE05DA
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         1120333864960 B (1.1 TB)
    Free Space:   4852801536 B (4.9 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume C06B9951-B54E-452A-A28D-3FC538D70099
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 5B93D0C3-CF34-4CB9-8405-2E18E598FD74
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999345012736 B (999.3 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family A9822895-14D4-4304-9167-BCD2C5F75269
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 2323EBF3-1631-4A3E-8078-6B5D506D09CD
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk3
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          1114478608384 B (1.1 TB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
-bash-3.2# gpt -r show disk0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  236306352      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  236715992     262144      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  236978136          7         
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
-bash-3.2# gpt -r show disk1
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1951845728      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1952255368     1269760      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1953525128           7         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Added the output of the commands to the question.

Comment: The output added looks fine. There are no hints of failing disks/volumes or bogus partition maps. Did you boot the Mac to an external drive/thumb drive with an older system? Did you already try to boot to Recovery Mode/Internet Recovery Mode and verify the disks there?

Comment: These commands were run from the recovery mode. Disk Utility's GUI gives more or less identical results. Also, fsck_hfs seems to always run in read-only mode.

Comment: Disk Utility is not always helpful. That said it may be time to invest in a 3rd party disk repair program. My go to is DiskWarrior, but there are others that many people swear by.

Comment: Each and every utility I tried, including DiskWarrior, treats my disk as read only (It's not mounted of course), even in single user mode. I even made a complete disk image of it, which is still treated as read only. fsck_hfs keeps printing "NO WRITE" no matter how and when I use it. For some reason though, in Single User Mode I am still able to see my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the CoreStorage logical volume has gone wrong, and effectively made my disk read-only. I solved it by doing the following steps:

1. Backed up the entire volume as a DMG file (to an external drive). The file must be formatted as Read/Write, since the partition is corrupt and therefore requires repair before it is mounted.
2. After the back up is complete, verify the DMG is mountable and the files are accessible.
3. From Disk Utility, Verify and Repair the DMG and remove any remaining errors.

At this point you should delete the original partition. But because CoreStorage made the disk effectively read only, it is not possible to reformat the disk. (Disk Utility will show the error "Unable to delete the core storage logical volume") So instead:

4. Delete the CoreStorage group from command line: `sudo diskutil cs deleteLVG A8FAA178-6011-40B8-9138-AC3500CE05DA`
5. In Disk Utility GUI, select one of the two drives that were split from the Fusion Drive. The GUI will ask you to merge them back to a Fusion Drive and format them for you.
6. Restore the DMG backup.